# Encoding and problem in viewing chars like "ö" "â" in android sqlite

Tags: android, encoding, sqlite, android-emulator

I am using a sqlite database which contains some chars like "ö" "ş" "â". sqlite encoding is utf-8. i connect to sqlite database from console with sqlite3.exe and can view the content of the database correctly. Chars are displayed correctly. However, when i connect to database and view them in android emulator in a listview, chars are corrupted and cannot view them properly. what should i don in order to display those chars correctly? Is it something related with sqlite or android or android emulator? I made many trys and i think the problem is not in the database or database encoding.

Comment: How are you adding the text to the database? This works fine for me, when I add non-ASCII characters to an SQLite database from Java and then display them in a ListView.

Comment: I used two methods: 1) importing from csv file. I can view the chars correctly in sqlite3 console. 2) inserting from sqlite console manually. I think i should write a java code to import from csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing from csv file through sqlite3 console corrupts the chars. I wrote a java code to import csv file, and it worked fine.Thanks to Christopher.